# If I can't stand theoretical questions of numerical analysis, does that mean I don't have a future in applied math research?

Tags: research-process, mathematics

Every math student has a good idea that there are virtually no academic jobs for pure math PhDs.  So, many go the applied route.

If I find questions of numerical analysis dull - even after hearing some of the leaders / experts of the field lecture in classes and learning about their great works - then do I have no future in applied mathematics?  I can't think of any research direction in applied math that doesn't use numerical analysis, eg, complexity theory, error analysis, approximation theory.  I couldn't make a career out of solving ode and pde.

Am I generally correct that I should not stay in mathematics if I am not interested in questions of numerical analysis?

Comment: "Every math student has a good idea that there are virtually no academic jobs for pure math PhDs." I find this false in two different ways.  First, hundreds of pure math PhDs receive academic jobs every year in the US alone.  Second, *more* hundreds want academic jobs, so, yes, the academic job market is competitive: in my experience, most students don't have a good idea of how competitive it is.  "So, many go the applied route." Wait, what?  There aren't any more academic jobs in applied math than pure math.  I have rarely if ever seen a student switch from pure to applied for this reason.

Comment: "Am I generally correct that I should not stay in mathematics if I am not interested in questions of numerical analysis?" No.

Comment: "Btw, would you say that number theory is the hardest subfield to make any partial progress in research? Is it a field where only a few dominate it and not wise for students to get into number theory, no matter how riveting the subject is?" Since I and my students are number theorists, I must answer **no** to the second question.  As for the first, it's not so meaningful to classify subfields of mathematics by difficulty.  For me, number theory is easier than differential geometry; for several friends and colleagues, the reverse.  Here's a tip: try doing what you like, as well as you can.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark it seems the question implies there are non-academic jobs in numerical analysis.

Comment: Wait, do you dislike just the *theory* of numerical analysis, or do you also dislike modeling, programming, using numerical methods, etc? Because there is a lot more in applied math than just determining convergence rates of approximations to PDEs, etc.

Comment: I happened to enjoy numerical analysis.  But there's so much more to applied math than just numerical analysis.  It's time for you to do some exploration of books and papers.  Also, look at some faculty bios from applied math departments, to see what people are working on.  And go to lots of seminars -- not just in applied math, but also in the fields you think you might want to apply math to.